# How can force a user to use a specific edition in Autonomous Database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

I am using [Edition Based Redefinition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adfns/editions.html#GUID-58DE05A0-5DEF-4791-8FA8-F04D11964906) in Autonomous Database. How can I force a user to use the edition I want?

Disclaimer: I am a product manager for Autonomous Database.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a logon trigger and the dbms_session package.

Here is an example. I create two editions with the admin user and I grant access to it for the test user.

```
SQL> create edition e1;

Edition created.

SQL> create edition e2;

Edition created.

SQL> grant use on edition e2 to test;

Grant succeeded.
```

Then I create a logon trigger that sets the edition for that user when she logs in.

```
create or replace trigger sess_logon
after logon on database
begin
if sys_context('USERENV','SESSION_USER') = 'TEST'
then
    DBMS_SESSION.SET_EDITION_DEFERRED ('E2');
end if;
END;
/
```

When this user logs in, she can see the current edition with this query.

```
SQL> select sys_context('userenv', 'current_edition_name') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_EDITION_NAME')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E2
```

Disclaimer: I am a product manager for Autonomous Database.